# segment.io together with another google analytics tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, segment-io

Is it possible to use segment.io with one classic google analytics tracking code concurrently with an extra universal google analytics tracking code(not integrated in segment.io) on the same page?

Thank you,

Comment: Yeah, you could do this without segment.io, too. It's called dual-tagging, and it's recommended if you're going to implement Universal Analytics, as it's still in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, absolutely. Classic GA loads their ga.js library, whereas Universal GA loads their analytics.js library.

You can load Universal inside Segment.io just be adding your universal UA-code into Segment.io, and then leave the old ga.js tag's in place as-is. Or at least that's probably the most straight-forward transition plan :)

Comment: This means that, if say, both codes were of the same type(classic or universal), one loaded in segment.io and the other loaded the analytics way, there would be a conflict possibly leading to erroneous tracking data because of duplicate library loading?

Comment: Yes, as of January 2014 if you have two of the same type loading on the same page,  that will currently create a conflict and lead to erroneous tracking data.